# Fiware - prevent data loss due to network issues between sensors and Orion

Tags: networking, iot, fiware, fiware-orion, opc-ua

I'm wondering about how to prevent data loss due to network issues between sensors and Fiware Orion.

Example:
A smart industry is using some sensors and actuators connected to PLC.
This PLC is an OPC UA server.
The OPC UA IoT agent is used to fetch and subscribe to this server's values and forward them to the context broker (Orion NGSIv2).

During one hour, a network problem / maintenance disconnect the IoT Agent from the OCP UA server (PLC). The production line is still producing data during this time.

Questions:

1. What is expected in this case ?
2. Do IoT agents can store data that are not successfully send to the context broker ?
3. Do OPC UA IoT agent is able to use OPC UA Historical Access (HA) to recover previous values ?

I set up a sandbox environment to test if it was possible to ask Orion for the history of data stored on the OPC UA server.
The IoT Agent documentation doesn't seem to address this topic.
This [documentation](https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture.html) is speaking about sensors making measurements every hour and sending data once everyday. It may be related ?

Thank you
Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a buffering mechanism for that. The IoT Agent could do it, but I'm not aware of anything like that being implemented.
Apart from "fixing the problem", you would also want to use a timestamp such as "observedAt" (NGSI-LD) or "dateObserved" (think that's the common one for NGSIv2). Cause, all unsent buffered updates would (once the network is back) be sent as a batch and they'd all have the same system timestamps (modifiedAt/createdAt).

Now, back to the problem, if you set up your IoT Agent to send updates not directly to the broker but to a "buffering gateway", you could implement the thing yourself. Should be quite straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will look to propose a generic functionality for this in the iotagent-node-lib project. I will add the github's issue link if I create one.

Can you explain what you mean by "buffering gateway" than I could implement myself appart ?